# Jasmine React Spy not being called?

Tags: reactjs, jasmine

I am new to jasmine testing in react and this is driving me crazy.

I am trying to test a simple button click below. But the spy isn't working.

```
    it('fires the clearTags handler', function() {

    var handler = jasmine.createSpy();

    var element = ReactTest.renderIntoDocument(
        React.createElement(SomeComponent)); 

    spyOn(element,'clearTags')

    var clearTagsLink = ReactTest.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(element, 'clear-tags-link');

    ReactTest.Simulate.click(clearTagsLink);

    expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I am getting the error Expected spy unknown to have been called. Any ideas? I have tried using .and.callThrough() but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Spy's are typically placed on method calls.  Any sort of method call within the method being spied on, will **not** be executed by Jasmine unless you attach and.callThrough like you have done.  However you're attaching a spy to a variable and not a method within the React library, which it appears you want to do.

If I'm correct, I would think you would want to setup your spy like so;

```
spyOn(React, 'createElement');
expect(React.createElement).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

For a more robust test you would probably want to use the jasmine toHaveBeenCalledWith("passing in parameters") you expected it to be called with.